# Problem with improper integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> I am supposed to calculate following integral:
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x\ln ^{p}x}dx$$

What I did was, that I substitute $\ln x=t$ and then I got:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{t^{p}}dt$$

But I do not know if it is right. What should I do next?

Comment: Note that $\ln$ is not defined at $0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, then it's simply an integral of a polynomial:

$$\int t^{-p}dt=\frac{t^{-p+1}}{-p+1}$$

P.S.: As @Naji notices, when $p=1$, then integral looks different:

$$\int t^{-1}dt=\ln{|t|}$$

Comment: And a special case for $p=1$, ofc

Comment: But what should I do with boundries of integral?

Comment: and Are they correct?

Comment: yes, as $x$ varies between $0$ and $1$, $\ln{x}$ - between $- \infty$ and $0$

Comment: @Naji you wrote that it is not defined in 0, but then when I made the substitution I got $-\infty$, what should I do with it?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Daniel as Andronicus has pointed out, the results are *not* always finite